# Any framework for customizing different view for different vendor?

Tags: java, jsp, frameworks, presentation

We have integration with several vendor for showing our product catalouge. Every-time, we have to customizing the view according to the provided templates by Vendor. 
I have find following points after analyzing all the templates i.e. as follows:

1. Commonly, i have found out there are total 6 different type of blocks. Let's suppose A,B,C,D,E,F.

Vendor *John* templates contains A,C,E. And the layout of the template is

```
          ---------------------- 
          |         A          |
          ----------------------
          |     C    |    E    |
          ----------------------
```

Vendor *Micheal* templates contains B,D,E,F. And the layout of the template is

```
          ---------------------- 
          |     B    |    F    |
          ----------------------
          |     D    |    E    |
          ----------------------
```

Vendor *Shane* templates contains A,B,C,D,E,F. And the layout of the template is

```
          ---------------------- 
          |     B    |    F    |
          ----------------------
          |     D    |    E    |
          ----------------------
          |     A    |    C    |
          ----------------------
```

1. Business logic for A,B,C,D,E,F is same in all the above case.
2. CSS, Image File and Html structure is different in all the above case.

I am trying to find out a generic solution where i can customize the view and prepare the presentation. Is there any framework in java who can help to solve my problem or any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) or [Sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/) might suit your needs. They're frameworks designed for "tiling" your view however you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I have to suggest Symfony for this purpose.

A single project contains several apps on a single data model where each app can be viewed as a view for somebody, a vendor or an administrator.

Plus, you can store some reusable pieces of templates at the root and re-use them inside each app the way you want.

You dont have to switch to Symfony, you can use just a part of it, and keep your data model at it is today.

http://www.symfony-project.org/

Comment: Thanks Jansen. I am a java developer. Sorry, i edited it and mentioned java in the question.